# renaming the output column with the plyr package in R

Tags: r, plyr

Hadley turned me on to the [plyr](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) package and I find myself using it all the time to do 'group by' sort of stuff. But I find myself having to always rename the resulting columns since they default to V1, V2, etc.

Here's an example:

```
mydata<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(144, mean=2, sd=2),72,2),c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),rep("C",24)))
colnames(mydata) <- c("x_value", "acres",  "state")
groupAcres <- ddply(mydata, c("state"), function(df)c(sum(df$acres)))
colnames(groupAcres) <- c("state","stateAcres")
```

Is there a way to make ddply name the resulting column for me so I can omit that last line?

Comment: JD- That first line of code doesn't run, should be rnorm(...,72,2), e.g.:

mydata<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(144, mean=2, sd=2),72,2),c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),rep("C",24)))'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
> groupAcres <- ddply(mydata, c("state"), function(df) c(myName=sum(df$acres)))
> groupAcres
  state   myName
1     A 56.87973
2     B 57.84451
3     C 52.82415
```

Comment: I muddle through R syntax without really understanding it. Why on earth does one need the concatenate function?

Comment: @Farrel: To give the data item a name. Using `data.frame` instead works as well.

Answer (score 19):

Use summarise (or summarize):

```
  groupAcres <- ddply(mydata, "state", summarise, 
     myName = sum(acres))
```

Comment: that is an excellent way to solve this. I chose Chris' answer only because it's more general. I'll use both his method and yours in the future. I wish I could combine them or accept them both

Comment: My method is actually slightly more general (because if you return multiple types they can have different types).  I wrote summarise for exactly this use.

Comment: I can't get this method to work for me because I am using the nrow function to sum the number of rows in the subsetted data, any tips?

Comment: @mindless.panda You can always use `length` on a column of the subsetted data, instead of `nrow`: `ddply(mydata, .(state), summarize, count.per.state=length(acres))`. (If you don't care about the column name, you can just use `nrow` as the aggregating function, but that's counter to the purpose of this thread.)