# How can I rename the output rows/cols of **ply functions from plyr?

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to state the row/col output names in a `**ply` function, `ldply`, from the plyr package.

for example,

I have a list, `foo`, that I want to convert to a `data.frame` and truncate significant digits with `signif()`

```
 foo <- list(var.a = runif(3), var.b = runif(3), var.c=runif(3))
```

What I have now is

```
q <- ldply(foo, signif, 2)
colnames(dq)[1] <- c('id', 'q1', 'q2','q3')
rownames(dq) <- dq$id
```

Is there an easier way?

Two previous questions have asked how to use plyr to rename [rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187448/how-do-i-use-plyr-to-number-rows) and [cols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395271/renaming-the-output-column-with-the-plyr-package-in-r) using plyr, but I think my question is different. Can the names be stated at the same time as another function (or if I am doing this correctly)? Is this a worthwhile feature request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to give names somewhere, either on the function being called inside as eg in

```
R> ldply(foo, function(l) c(a=signif(l[1], 2), b=signif(l[2], 2), 
+                           c=signif(l[3], 2)))
    .id    a    b    c
1 var.a 0.50 0.72 0.27
2 var.b 0.82 0.38 0.24
3 var.c 0.13 0.27 0.81
R>
```

or has you did after the call.

Another option I frequently use is to explicitly create one-row `data.frame` in the anonymous worker function.  `*dply()` et al then simply collated these into a single `data.frame`.  That works well enough for my tastes.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of your option 2? It sounds useful, but I'm not intuitively understanding how it would work. Thanks.

Comment: See eg my older answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277326/group-by-in-r-ddply-with-weighted-mean and in general, try searches of the form "[r] someterm" to look for 'someterm' within R tags on StackOverflow.  I just did for `ddply` and the first two hits were winners.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought to search SO for a similar answer.