# Rename .id column in ldply

Tags: r, plyr

Is there a way to assign a custom name to the column that is normally named `.id` in the result of `ldply`?

```
> ldply(setNames(1:3, 1:3), function(i) data.frame(j=1/i))
  .id         j
1   1 1.0000000
2   2 0.5000000
3   3 0.3333333
```

I know I can call `rename` on the result, but I'd like to do it in one call. Any suggestions?

Note that `adply` suffers from a similar problem:

```
> adply(as.array(setNames(1:3, 1:3)), 1, function(i) data.frame(j=1/i))
  X1         j
1  1 1.0000000
2  2 0.5000000
3  3 0.3333333
```

Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338325/how-can-i-rename-the-output-rows-cols-of-ply-functions-from-plyr) addresses the issue of renaming the "data" columns, but the answer also fails to provide a solution for the `.id` column.

Comment: I don't think so (but would be happy to be wrong); maybe you can write your own wrapper function that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem comfortable using setNames, so you can move the "j" and the "newname" assingment to a convenient wrapper.

```
setNames( ldply(setNames(1:3, 1:3), function(i) data.frame(1/i)) , c("newname", "j") )
  newname         j
1       1 1.0000000
2       2 0.5000000
3       3 0.3333333
```

Comment: Yeah, this or some other wrapper is the only way I know to do this.  The implication is that the OP is trying to assign a metaname to the list of names in the original list, which violates the logic of the 'ldply' function.  Even easier (on the eyes, at least), would be to simply change the ".id" column name afterwards with a line like `names(data_Frame)[1] <- "newname"`

Answer (score 4):

I have [proposed](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/pull/143) an [implementation](https://github.com/muelleki/plyr), let's see if it makes it into official `plyr`. Basically, a new parameter `.idname` that allows specifying the name of the `.id` column, with an option to drop it altogether by passing `NULL`:

```
> ldply(setNames(1:3, 1:3), function(i) data.frame(j=1/i), .idname='i')
  i         j
1 1 1.0000000
2 2 0.5000000
3 3 0.3333333
```

. Install the tweaked version using

```
library(devtools)
install_github('plyr', 'krlmlr', ref='140-142-id')
```

**EDIT**: This is now available in `plyr` 1.8.1 on CRAN:

```
> ldply(setNames(nm=1:3), function(i) data.frame(j=1/i), .id='i')
```

Comment: I just found that with `ldply`, the `.id` values are pulled from the `names` of the input "`list`". So, if the list is a list of data for different levels on which you later want to aggregate (for example), make sure the list has names, such as `names(mylist) <- seq_along(mylist)`.  The column named by the`.id` argument will not show up if the names of the input list is NULL.

Comment: This comment is underrated. Was wanting to use ldply function bind together csv files and retain the names of the files as a new column. Setting names of the list as names(mylist) <- paste(mylist) then running the ldply script allowed that. Thank you.