# New dataframe with count values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe "forum" that basically looks like this:

```
post-id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
user-id: 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
subforum-id: 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

Now I'm trying to create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
subforum-id: 1, 2, 3, ...
number-of-users-that-posted-only-once-to-this-subforum: ...
number-of-users-that-posted-more-than-n-times-to-this-subforum: ...
```

Is there any way to do that without pre-fabricating all the counts?

Comment: Please also show what have you tried till now. SO is not a place to get your code written for free. Also telling what have you tried till now also shows that you are really looking to learn from the solution and are not just after solution

Comment: Maybe have a look at `summarize()` in the **plyr** package. Here's one of many SO answers that demo's its use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395271/renaming-the-output-column-with-the-plyr-package-in-r/1396938#1396938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `plyr` and `summarise`:

```
# N = 1 here
ddply(DF, .(subforum.id), summarise, once = sum(table(user.id) == 1), 
                           n.times = sum(table(user.id) > N))

#   subforum.id once n.times
# 1           1    1       1
# 2           2    1       0
# 3           3    1       0
```

---

This is the `data.frame` DF:

```
DF <- structure(list(post.id = 1:5, user.id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                subforum.id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)), 
                .Names = c("post.id", "user.id", "subforum.id"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Arun! (Again, I guess ...) That's exactly what I was looking for. BTW: I wasn't trying to get anything for free, and I don't like that kind of attitude either. But it is very hard to express things when you have no idea what you're looking for ... R's definitely giving me trouble.

Comment: +1 for showing the `plyr` approach. I'm not a `plyr` user in general, so its interesting for me to see essentially the same answer as mine but with a different approach.

Comment: @Bob, I think the main point is that a good question should also show what you have tried so far. It is sometimes easier for people to pick up where you left off. Also, that exploration is an important part for learning how to minimize the trouble that R will give you. Finally, some sample data is always nice.

Comment: I see your point and I will definitely try to follow that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic idea *to get you started*: Use `table` to get a count of user ids by subforum ids and work from there:

```
> mydf <- structure(list(post.id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), user.id = c(1, 1, 
2, 3, 4), subforum.id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("post.id", 
"user.id", "subforum.id"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
> mytable <- with(mydf, table(subforum.id, user.id))
> mytable
           user.id
subforum.id 1 2 3 4
          1 2 1 0 0
          2 0 0 1 0
          3 0 0 0 1
```

Hint: from there, look at the `rowSums` function, and think about what happens if you sum over a logical vector.